# Word before and after a "=" symbol

Tags: grep, cut

I am trying to write some code which displays the word before an = symbol and after it based on user input.  For example, if a user enters `Name=john` the output would be:

```
The variable is called: Name

The variable value is: john
```

If the is no value after the = sign

```
The variable is called: Name

The variable value is:

Invalid entry
```

The user input is stored in a variable called `setting`

```
echo -e "The variable name of the setting is:" $setting | cut -d "=" -f1

value=$setting

echo -e "The variable value of the setting is:" $value | cut -d "=" -f2
    
case $value in
    
"") echo "Invalid setting"
    
esac

break
```

Ive tried using grep but run into the same issues with the text of the second line not displaying. i.e. a blank line or in this case just the word john

Comment: You haven't actually _said_ what the issue is here, so referring to the "same issues" only works to make the reader rather confused. Anyway, consider how the pipeline `cmd1 | cmd2` works. You have `echo some stuff | cut some args` there; think about what the input to `cut` is, and what it does with it.

Comment: Why do you use `case` for a one-case-only situation?

Comment: `IFS='=' read -r variable value` (I.e. read the data from the user and split it on `=` immediately. Don't parse it later.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You set `value` to be the whole user input `setting`, then you cut the string for `echo`, but you don't change `value`, so it still contains the whole string when you test it for being empty.

And I suggest to you variable expansion rather than `cut`:

```
printf '%s\n' "The variable name of the setting is: ${setting%%=*}"
value="${setting#*=}"
printf '%s\n' "The variable value of the setting is: $value"
case $value in
  "") echo >&2 "Invalid setting";;
esac
```